# SQL - How can I count distinct IDs for each day within the last 7 days?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, grouping, distinct-values

So, I'm trying to get the number of distinct users the registered sales on the last 7 days, for each day. Here's a sample of the table I have:

```
ID      Date   
1    2018-01-01
2    2018-01-02
3    2018-01-03
3    2018-01-04
2    2018-01-05
4    2018-01-06
5    2018-01-07
2    2018-01-08
```

Here's the outcome that I'd expect:

```
Distinct IDs      Date   
1               2018-01-01
2               2018-01-02
3               2018-01-03
3               2018-01-04
3               2018-01-05
4               2018-01-06
5               2018-01-07
4               2018-01-08
```

It's as if I as counting the distinct ID's in groups of the date and the 6 days before it. Any ideas?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What have you tried so far????

Comment: Some people are voting to close this question as "unclear" -> please see last sentence of OP which seem pretty to clear to me. For each date, OP wants to have the count of unique ids linked with the "current" date and the 6 previous days before it. In particular the value of distinct IDs will never exceed 7. @Guilherme : however, it is often expected from a question on SO to show some attempt/effort at solving your own problem, and explain why it was wrong, your question will be better received that way. Also, remove one of the tags and as Gordon Linoff said, tag with with your db system.

Comment: @Guilherme : you could also clarify some "edge cases" for your problem : In the example data you provide, there is exactly one ID corresponding to each date. Also, there seems to be an id for every day. Can we assume this will always be the case within the context of your problem?

Comment: @Pac0 thanks for the feedbacks! I'll keep that in mind on my next question ;) Gordon solved it perfectly!

Comment: I saw that, I upvoted his answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest method is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.date,
       (select count(distinct t2.id)
        from t t2
        where t2.date >= t.date - interval '6 day' and t2.date <= t.date
       ) as uniques_7day
from (select distinct date
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note that you haven't specified the database, so this uses ANSI/ISO standard SQL syntax.